# Find the Smith Canonical Matrix

Tags: matrices

I need to find the Smith Canonical Matrix Equivalent to the characteristic matrix of
$
J=\mathrm{diag}[J_{2}(1), 1, -1]
$

where 
$$
J=
\pmatrix{
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
}
$$

I am using the textbook " Matrices and Linear Transformations" by Cullen.

The characteristic matrix is:

$$
xI-J=
\pmatrix{
x-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & x-1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & x-1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & x+1\\
}
$$

The book has thereom 6.13 which says

For every $A(x) \in F[x]_{nxn} $is equivalent to a unique matrix:
$S(x)=\mathrm{diag}[f_{1}(x), \dots, f_{r}(x), 0]$ where

$$f_{t}(x)=\frac{d_{t}(x)}{d_{t-1}(x)}=\frac{\gcd( t \times t \text{ subdeterminants of } A(x) )}{\gcd((t-1) \times (t-1) \text{ subdeterminants of }A(x)) }
$$

These are the answers I got:
\begin{align*}
f_{1}(x) & =1, \\
f_{2}(x) & =(x-1), \\
f_{3}(x) & =(x-1), \\
f_{4}(x) & =(x-1)^{2}(x+1).
\end{align*}
The textbook says that 
$f_{2}=1$

I need to know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The minor with rows $2$ and $4$ and columns $1$ and $4$ is $-(x+1)$, which isn't divisible by $x-1$.